# UIScrollView ContentSize height too large

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that should only scroll horizontally.  The scroll view is pinned to the bottom of the screen.  I have set auto layout constraints to a fixed height.  I set the contentSize to a fixed size.

However, when I run the application the content is showing half of it off the bottom of the screen. And it will scroll vertically for what seems to be about 200 pixels.

I have a map and a label pinned above the scroll view and the layout looks exactly as I want, except the content of the scroll view seems off.  This is the code I've written:

in my .h file:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 100)];

// add some content
UIView *personView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 8, 100, self.scrollView.frame.size.height-16)];
personView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

UIView *personView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 8, 100, self.scrollView.frame.size.height-16)];
personView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIView *personView3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 8, 100, self.scrollView.frame.size.height-16)];
personView3.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

UIView *personView4 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(330, 8, 100, self.scrollView.frame.size.height-16)];
personView4.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

[self.scrollView addSubview:personView];
[self.scrollView addSubview:personView2];
[self.scrollView addSubview:personView3];
[self.scrollView addSubview:personView4];
```

I don't use UIScrollView that often, so am I missing something?  Does anyone know where the sizing problem could be coming from?

Also I did an NSLog on the frame height and contentSize height and both equal 100.

**Edit:**

This view is in a navigation controller and I set the navigation bar from hidden = YES to hidden = NO on first load.  I've noticed that the content height is different when I leave it hidden, so this must have something to do with it.

Comment: If you're using constraints, you should not set the `contentSize`. You should use constraints to control `contentSize`. Read [Technical Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

Comment: @robmayoff is there a way to work around using constraints for contentSize, seems like theres an easier solution.  Also you left out panama at the end of your palindrome on your bio :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set your scrollView's Content size int "viewDidLayoutSubviews" method with keeping the autolayouts set.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
  [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(required_width, required_height)];
}
```

Check the Navigation Bar set to the ViewController in the Storyboard as well. If there is any, try removing it.

And please lemme know if you still face some problem.

Comment: Yes, still seeing the same results.  When I push the view it has this problem, but when I presentViewController it looks like I want. Seems to me this is a problem with having it in the NavigationController

Comment: The problem is then, I believe, with your layouts. Did you set your constraints of UIScrollView with the SuperView's "Layout Guide" or "Container Margin"?

Comment: everything is connected to superview, I replaced the navigation controller with a navigation bar object and it looks like expected.

Comment: This problem that you mentioned occurs when you attach your constraints to Container Margin. Please do me a favour and try putting navigationController back and attach the UIScrollView Constraints to "Layout Guide" of its parent View. I beleive it would look like as expected no matter you show/hide the navigation bar. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I solved it.  Problem was with the Navigation Bar.  On my ViewController I had top bar set to Opaque Navigation Bar.  When I removed it the view had correct layout.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I tried top pinned to "Top Layout Guide" and "Superview" and it didn't change anything.  If you want to update your answer though I can mark it as correct since you were the only one that helped me!